# Why does Mathematica 11.1 use so much memory on my system

Tags: memory, resource-management

On my Mac OS X 10.10.5 system, here are the results of calling `MemoryInUse[]` immediately after startup (fresh front end, fresh kernel) on various versions of *Mathematica*:

[image]

As you can see, *Mathematica* 11.1 uses up a lot more memory than the previous version  (I wonder if that explains why it feels much less responsive and takes much longer to load than earlier versions).

Can you reproduce this on your system?  Does anyone know why version 11.1 in particular uses so much memory?

Comment: On my system both mma 11.1 and mma 11.2 used a lot of memory, approximately 100-110MB. Did you figure out why by now?

Comment: @Turgon Unfortunately I haven’t.  Im still looking for an answer, and also a solution to lower the memory footprint.